# this script breaks in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We have written this script. Essentially, it limits the input into a form field, to numerics only.

However we get an ie. error of 'value' is null or not an object. Any suggestions as to a fix please.

```
function numbersonly(e, decimal) {
var key;
var keychar;

if (window.event) {
   key = window.event.keyCode;
}
else if (e) {
   key = e.which;
}
else {
   return true;
}
keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) ||  (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) ) {
   return true;
}
else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1)) {
   return true;
}
else if (decimal && (keychar == ".")) { 
  return true;
}
else
   return false;
}
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
```

Form element is:

```
input id="landprice" name="landprice" size="50" type="text" class="medium" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,8);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,8);" maxlength="8"
```

Not sure what ie doesnt like.

Comment: Do you have a public page URL where this is used? Makes my debugging of your code faster and easier. The most common IE issue is trailing commas (IE breaks on them). But that's not the issue here.

Comment: Not public, but we do have a live page where this is. This is a dev project and cannot currently put a public link here.

Comment: Stick it on a dev server that is available on the internet. Amazon will give you a dev server for free. See http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: How do i share the link to you, without it becoming publicly viewable lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending "this.form.limitedtextfield" to limitText function and then trying to access property "value", based on my testing you will get error that you described if there is no  input field with id "limitedtextfield" on the page.

EDIT based on comments:
Try it like this:

```
<input id="countdown"/>
<input id="landprice" name="landprice" size="50" type="text" class="medium" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" onKeyDown="limitText(this,this.form.countdown,8);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this,this.form.countdown,8);" maxlength="8"/>
```

EDIT 2:
If you don't need the counter then change your limitText function like this:

```
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: well spotted.
So should the id be changed to limitText or > limitField ?
Currently input id is ( input id="landprice" )

Comment: Thinking change to: input name="limitedtextfield"

Comment: changed input name
Now we get 

'undefined'is null or not an object

Comment: Then you are still missing input element with id "countdown".

Comment: Error has gone , but now we have two input form fields. Plus that breaks the code, completely. Hmmmm

Comment: Essentially similar to this: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html

But only accept numbers, and we dont need the counter. But we do need to limit the number of numerals entered, in this case to 8. Just dont need to display character count

Comment: Then you will need to change javascript function limitText, if you are absolutely sure that you don't use counter anywhere else on your website otherwise it  will break other parts of your website that are using the same function.

Comment: No we dont, but.. we need to ensure a max limit of characters can be typed into the form field, and also in this instance ensure that numbers are only entered.
Not quite sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the value of variable `decimal`? I see where it is referenced, but not where it is set.

Added: Nevermind, it is a param to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok we fixed it:

Thanks guys.

```
function numbersonly(e, decimal) {
var key;
var keychar;

if (window.event) {
   key = window.event.keyCode;
}
else if (e) {
   key = e.which;
}
else {
   return true;
}
keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) ||  (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) ) {
   return true;
}
else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1)) {
   return true;
}
else if (decimal && (keychar == ".")) { 
  return true;
}
else
   return false;
}
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
}
```

And form field changed to:

```
input id="landprice" name="limitedtextfield" size="50" type="text" class="medium" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form,8);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form,8);" maxlength="8"/
```